# At what level does low oil prevent vtec from working?

Tags: honda, oil, vtec

Just got my first vtec honda and vtec isn't kicking In and before I take it to my mechanic to see what it is I'm curious to know how low the oil has to be to effect the vtec. My oil level is just in the optimum range but I read that high revs starve your engine of oil so I was wondering if just that tiny amount of lower oil level may be causing my vtec to not work? I know I can just go get some oil to see if it fixes it but I'd like to know for future references just how low the oil has to get to effect vtec

Comment: It would help if you let us know exactly which vehicle and engine you have.

Comment: If your oil level is between the min and max marks, the oil level should not be impacting the VTEC operation.

Answer (score 4):

If you look at your engines dip stick you will see minimum and maximum marks on it. The engine oil level must be maintained between these marks, any cause that means that this is not the case must be rectified. Carry a can of oil in the boot/trunk for topping up. The engine oil lubricates the moving parts, cools internal parts of the engine, and operates actuators on the engine such as Vtec valve. If the Vtec is not working, checking it must include an electrical check of  the solonoid valve and it's operation, and the working parts of Vtec mechanism. This usually means a visit to the repair shop. High revs on their own will not starve the engine of oil, but an extremely low oil level, or a fault with the oil pump, or oil lubrication system will.

Comment: Does vtec use an electrically actuated valve? I thought it was entirely based on oil pressure.

Answer (score 1):

My Honda with V V T has surged like the Solenoid screen was dirty or solenoid was trying to activate at 2500 RPM..  I've changed the oil, checked the two screens, changed to a little heavier oil. Each seemed to correct the problem for a while, I come to the conclusion that if the oil level drops below half between the min and max on the stick I have the same problem, adding oil to the max mark seems to rectify the problem.